# Flag Data in Excel Programatially

Tags: sql, excel

I have two sheets in an excel workbook. One of the sheets has 8 ID numbers. The other sheet has about 5000 rows, not every row matches one of the ID numbers on the other sheet. I want to flag the rows where an ID number is an exact match to the other sheet and extract them to a separate sheet.

At the moment I was thinking I could just type in

```
=IF(A2=sheet2!b3,1,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b4,2,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b5,3,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b6,4,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b7,5,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b8,6,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b9,7,0) OR IF(A2=sheet2!b10,8,0)
```

Then copy and paste them to a separate sheet, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix your formula for all the 8 ID's, but you should be able to add additional checks.

```
=IF(A2=$B$3;1; IF(A2=$B$4;2; IF(A2=$B$5;3;0)))
```

This basically reads as:

- compare A2 with B3, if they match return 1 (note the use of $ sign in order to always use the B3 cell, this is called [absolute cell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/get-to-know-excel-enter-formulas-RZ006107930.aspx?section=13) reference)
- if it doesn't match then compare A2 with B4 and if that matches return 2
- if it doesn't match then compare A2 with B5 and if that matches return 3
- if it doesn't match return 0

If you wish to compare to all 8 IDs you should just nest the if's a bit more.

A simpler solution would be to use [VLOOKUP](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this fantastic answer. How do you then extract this selected data and place it on a separate sheet?

Comment: You can use the same logic you used, replace =$B$3 with sheet2!$B$3. I only simplified it since the nested if's are hard to read even without that :)